# Basis of a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove the following statement:

> If $B=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^5$ and $V$ is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^5$, then $V$ has a basis made of just two members of $B$.

How I tried to solve it:

> Let $a=(1,0,0,0,0),b=(0,1,0,0,0),c=(0,0,1,0,0),d=(0,0,0,1,0),e=(0,‌​0,0,0,1)$ form a basis $\mathbb R^5$. Let the two elements of V be $(1,0,0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1,10)$. Here they are not forming basis by taking any two of $a,b,c,d,e$. That's why it is not a basis. Is this right ?

Comment: Here's a lower dimensional, more concrete example that might help. We know that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ together form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $V$ be the one-dimensional subspace defined by the line $x=y$. Does $V$ have a basis made from one of the previous basis elements?

Comment: yes, because either we get first or second set.

Comment: Sorry, what are these first and second sets?

Comment: And are either of those vectors a basis element for the set $V = \{ (x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$, the line $x=y$?

Comment: What have you tried on your own, Kkumar?  Because what I see is your post telling us to prove what you've been asked to prove. You haven't provided any information as to where, in your current studies, this problem comes up, nor have you given us any idea what you know, and/or, what specifically is it that leaves you stuck. I suggest you address some of the points I mention here, and in particular, you demonstrate by adding work you've done on the problem, that you've tried.

Comment: sir , I want to ask whether I have to take two elements of B  for V or not?

Comment: You're telling us to solve a problem given to you.  That is not a question.  You have not answered my questions:  most importantly, what have **you** tried?  If you think that you've wasted an hour because your command to users here to prove or disprove your problem for you, and haven't received an answer yet, you have a lot to learn about the site.  Those who answer questions do so voluntarily; even the elected moderators of this site volunteer all the time they spend on the site. You are not entitled to answers.  Hence, you might try attracting answers by doing some of the things I suggested

Comment: how I tried to solve it: let a=(1,0,0,0,0);b(0,1,0,0,0);c=(0,0,1,0,0);d=(0,0,0,1,0);e=(0,0,0,0,1) are in R^5..                     Let two elements of V be (1,0,0,1,1)and (1,0,1,10).           here they are not forming basis by taking any two of a,b,c,d,e.       that's way it is not a basis.                               is this right ?

Comment: What is $V$ in your counterexample? You may be on to something, but it is also possible that you have serious conceptual misunderstandings about subspaces.

Comment: It seems clear to me that the statement is false. Using $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ as the standard basis vectors (just like you did); if $V$ is the space generated by $(1,0,0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1,1,1)$; you can not make a basis for it using two members of $B$. I think your counterexample is correct (also, I don't understand why the question is [on hold]...)

Comment: @DanielCunha The question was put on hold as OP had previously show no effort in solving the question and merely just demanded answer to a question.

Comment: @KkumarTanwar Your reasoning is incorrect as basis is not unique. You need to show that no two elements of $B$ can form a basis of $V$. Further what do you mean by ".. be **the** two elements of V"? Which two elements. I think you mean they span $V$.

Comment: To illustrate the gap in your reasoning that you need to fill in: suppose you had naively let $V$ be the space generated by $(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 2, 0, 0, 0)$.  Then $V$ also has another basis given by $\{ a, b \}$ so that wouldn't work even though the original basis you chose wasn't from among $a, b, c, d, e$.